# CMake doesn't work with Google Protobuf

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

Unable to link protobuf library using CMake. My CMakeLists is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(addressbook)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(PROJECT_NAME addressbook)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(proto)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

and in proto subdirectory there is another CMakeLists.txt (that way it is done in github repo https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example)

```
INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER message.proto)
ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
```

But my IDE still outputs buch of lines like

> CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>   /home/camille/ClionProjects/protobuf/main.cpp:42: undefined reference
>   to`google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)'
>   /home/camille/ClionProjects/protobuf/main.cpp:49: undefined reference
>   to `tutorial::AddressBook::AddressBook()'
>   /home/camille/ClionProjects/protobuf/main.cpp:54: undefined reference
>   to`google::protobuf::Message::ParseFromIstream(std::istream*)'

Where is my mistake? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 10):

Your program fails to link because `${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}` is empty in the scope of your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. This happens because calling `add_subdirectory` creates a child scope, and the `Protobuf_XXX` variables set by `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` are only in that child scope.

A good way to fix this is to add the following to `proto/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(proto INTERFACE ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

This instructs targets that link to `proto` to also link to `${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}`. Now you can simplify `target_link_libraries` in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(addressbook proto)
```

On a side note, you could also use e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ... )
```

`${PROJECT_NAME}` resolves to whatever you have set in the `project(...)` statement in that `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Finally, note that this links to `Protobuf_LIBRARIES` instead of `PROTOBUF_LIBRARY`. `Protobuf_LIBRARIES` includes both the Protocol Buffers libraries and the dependent Pthreads library.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for variable name case: With CMake 3.6 and later, the `FindProtobuf` module input and output variables were all renamed from `PROTOBUF_` to `Protobuf_` (see [release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/release/3.6.html#other-changes)), so using `Protobuf_` works with CMake 3.6, but fails with undefined reference with an earlier version.

To be on the safe side, either use the old style

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}))
```

or force everyone to use at least CMake 3.6

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
```

Also, there is a [resolved bug report](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17708) in the Kitware cmake issue tracker with more information on how to diagnose such issues.

Answer (score 2):

The variable you need to pass to `target_link_libraries` is `Protobuf_LIBRARIES`. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindProtobuf.html).

Answer (score 1):

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(protobuf)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)

FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER addressbook.proto)
ADD_LIBRARY(proto2 ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(proto2)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(protobuf main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(protobuf proto2 ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Bad idea to keep everything in the root `CMakeLists.txt`. Also name `proto2` is not very professional.

Comment: It is just a exampel, sorry for that