# Google Protobuf 3: Undefined Reference Errors when building with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu (16) for C++ development. When I tried to include "Google Protocol Buffers" using the instructions that can be found here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md ->

```
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig # refresh shared library cache.
```

Typing the following command does output the right results, so the installation of GPB is okay, isn't it?

```
> protoc --version
libprotoc 3.2.0
```

But when I try to build my application using cmake ->

```
cmake .. && make
client
/home/manuel/Schreibtisch/Repositories/Projekt/maurer/src/main.cpp/home/manuel/Schreibtisch/Repositories/Projekt/maurer/include/TerminalColors.h/home/manuel/Schreibtisch/Repositories/Projekt/maurer/include/Functions.h/home/manuel/Schreibtisch/Repositories/Projekt/maurer/include/URL.h
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/manuel/Schreibtisch/Repositories/Projekt/maurer/build
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable client
CMakeFiles/client.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In Funktion `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5a8b): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5b10): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::SerializeToOstream(std::ostream*) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5bd0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::ParseFromIstream(std::istream*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5cf0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited[abi:cxx11]()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev]+0x5): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::protobuf_person_2eproto::(anonymous namespace)::protobuf_AssignDescriptors()':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x6e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&, google::protobuf::internal::MigrationSchema const*, google::protobuf::Message const* const*, unsigned int const*, google::protobuf::MessageFactory*, google::protobuf::Metadata*, google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const**, google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor const**)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::protobuf_person_2eproto::(anonymous namespace)::protobuf_RegisterTypes(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&)':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x108): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::RegisterAllTypes(google::protobuf::Metadata const*, int)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::protobuf_person_2eproto::TableStruct::InitDefaultsImpl()':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x15e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x163): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::InitProtobufDefaults()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::protobuf_person_2eproto::AddDescriptorsImpl()':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x19e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x1ad): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&))'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x1b7): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdown(void (*)())'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::Person(test::Person const&)':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x3a6): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x402): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x830): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadTagFallback(unsigned int)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x90a): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x9ce): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xa1d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::SkipField(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xadb): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xafe): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xb34): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteInt32(int, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xb90): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xbb3): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(bool, unsigned char*) const':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xc2e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xceb): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::VerifyUtf8String(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Operation, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xe48): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xe5e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xe76): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xe8a): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xeb7): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(google::protobuf::Message const&, google::protobuf::Message*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xee5): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person::MergeFrom(test::Person const&)':
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xf71): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xf87): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xfa2): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0xfb6): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x10a8): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x10f2): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
person.pb.cc:(.text+0x1145): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::Closure::Closure()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf7ClosureC2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf7ClosureC5Ev]+0x9): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::Closure'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0::FunctionClosure0(void (*)(), bool)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal16FunctionClosure0C2EPFvvEb[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal16FunctionClosure0C5EPFvvEb]+0x22): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::IsDefaultSerializationDeterministic()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStream35IsDefaultSerializationDeterministicEv[_ZN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStream35IsDefaultSerializationDeterministicEv]+0x7): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::default_serialization_deterministic_'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32(unsigned int*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf2io16CodedInputStream12ReadVarint32EPj[_ZN6google8protobuf2io16CodedInputStream12ReadVarint32EPj]+0x78): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32Fallback(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32(unsigned int)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStream12VarintSize32Ej[_ZN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStream12VarintSize32Ej]+0x1e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32Fallback(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::CreateInstanceNoArena(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x4b): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x61): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x79): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x8d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr21CreateInstanceNoArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xdc): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(long*, void (*)())':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE[_ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE]+0x5e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(long*, google::protobuf::Closure*)'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE[_ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE]+0x6a): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0::~FunctionClosure0()'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE[_ZN6google8protobuf14GoogleOnceInitEPlPFvvE]+0x7b): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0::~FunctionClosure0()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::Clear()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf15UnknownFieldSet5ClearEv[_ZN6google8protobuf15UnknownFieldSet5ClearEv]+0x20): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::ClearFallback()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena::DoMergeFrom(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal25InternalMetadataWithArena11DoMergeFromERKNS0_15UnknownFieldSetE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal25InternalMetadataWithArena11DoMergeFromERKNS0_15UnknownFieldSetE]+0x70): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena::default_instance()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal25InternalMetadataWithArena16default_instanceEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal25InternalMetadataWithArena16default_instanceEv]+0x5): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::MessageLite::MessageLite()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteC2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteC5Ev]+0x9): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::MessageLite'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteD2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteD5Ev]+0xd): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::MessageLite'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::Message::Message()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf7MessageC2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf7MessageC5Ev]+0x19): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::Message'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::Message::~Message()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf7MessageD2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf7MessageD5Ev]+0xd): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vtable for google::protobuf::Message'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadString(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
>*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10ReadStringEPNS0_2io16CodedInputStreamEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10ReadStringEPNS0_2io16CodedInputStreamEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x1f): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
>*)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringToArray(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&, unsigned char*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite18WriteStringToArrayEiRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPh[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite18WriteStringToArrayEiRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPh]+0x39): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits
<char>
, std::allocator
<char>
> const&, unsigned char*)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `void google::protobuf::Arena::Own
<test::Person>
(test::Person*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf5Arena3OwnIN4test6PersonEEEvPT_[_ZN6google8protobuf5Arena3OwnIN4test6PersonEEEvPT_]+0x4d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `test::Person const* google::protobuf::internal::DynamicCastToGenerated
<test::Person const>
(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal22DynamicCastToGeneratedIKN4test6PersonEEEPT_PKNS0_7MessageE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal22DynamicCastToGeneratedIKN4test6PersonEEEPT_PKNS0_7MessageE]+0x37): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o: In Funktion `google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArenaBase<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet, google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena>::mutable_unknown_fields_slow()':
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv]+0xbd): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned long)'
person.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv]+0x118): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN4test6PersonE[_ZTVN4test6PersonE]+0x20): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN4test6PersonE[_ZTVN4test6PersonE]+0x58): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN4test6PersonE[_ZTVN4test6PersonE]+0x60): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN4test6PersonE[_ZTVN4test6PersonE]+0xa8): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN4test6PersonE[_ZTVN4test6PersonE]+0xb0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed() const'
CMakeFiles/client.dir/person.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4test6PersonE[_ZTIN4test6PersonE]+0x10): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/client.dir/build.make:129: die Regel für Ziel „client“ scheiterte
make[2]: *** [client] Fehler 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: die Regel für Ziel „CMakeFiles/client.dir/all“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Fehler 2
Makefile:83: die Regel für Ziel „all“ scheiterte
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
>
```

I already tried to completely re-build the application (deleted build-folder) and also re-installed GoogleProtocolBuffers in different versions. This is my CMakeLists.txt-File ->

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(18_HTTPClient)  # change xxx to your project name

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)  # change if necessary

add_definitions(-DASIO_STANDALONE)

if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU" OR
    "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  #add_definitions(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion)
  # add_definitions(-Wl,--no-as-needed)  # needed for building on buggy configurations
else()
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF)
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_STD_ARRAY)
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_CSTDINT)
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_STD_SHARED_PTR)
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_STD_TYPE_TRAITS)
  add_definitions(-DASIO_HAS_STD_ATOMIC)
  add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501)
  add_definitions(/Wall /EHsc)
endif()

find_package(Threads)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(include/STLPlus)

# important: Don't forget to set the environment variable accordingly (if needed)!
include_directories($ENV{ASIO_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories($ENV{SPDLOG_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories($ENV{FMT_PATH})  # should refer to the root directory of fmt
include_directories($ENV{JSON_INCLUDE_PATH})  # should refer to the directory 'src' of json

set(FMT_LIB_PATH $ENV{FMT_PATH}/fmt/fmt/libfmt.a)
#set(FMT_LIB_PATH $ENV{FMT_PATH}/build/fmt/libfmt.a)

# only needed for protobuf
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
file(GLOB protos protos/*.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${protos})

macro(create_targets)
  if(${ARGC} GREATER 1)
    foreach(curr_target ${ARGV})
      message(${curr_target})
      # includes are only for usage with QtCreator!
      file(GLOB sources src/${curr_target}/*.cpp src/*.cpp include/${curr_target}/*.h include/*.h)
      add_executable(${curr_target} ${sources} ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
      target_link_libraries(${curr_target} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${FMT_LIB_PATH} ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
    endforeach(curr_target)
  else()
    message(${ARGV0})
    IF(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/${ARGV0}" AND IS_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/${ARGV0}")
      file(GLOB sources src/${ARGV0}/*.cpp src/*.cpp include/${ARGV0}/*.h include/*.h)
    else()
      file(GLOB sources src/*.cpp include/*.h)
    endif()
    message(${sources})
    add_executable(${ARGV0} ${sources} ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
    target_link_libraries(${ARGV0} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${FMT_LIB_PATH} ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
  endif()
endmacro(create_targets)

# replace xxx with list of executables
# like: create_targets(exe) or create_targets(exe1 exe2 exe3)
# if just one target is given -> source files are in 'src'
# else -> source files specific for each target are in respective
#   subdirectories of 'src' like in 'src/exe1', 'src/exe2', and 'src/exe3'
#   common source files are in 'src'
create_targets(client)
```

Any suggestions about what I can do about this? Thank's in advance. If you need any further details or file-contents, i'll upload them as fast as possible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your help - edited the question and added CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Probably you miss linking the right library. Reduce your example further, it is to long to wade through.

Comment: I would guess that you may be running into some kind of ABI compatibility issue from mixing C++11 and C++14.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41043184

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using a cmake version earlier than 3.6. If so, either upgrading or using `PROTOBUF_` instead of `Protobuf_` might solve your problem; see also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586477) for details.