# faild to link protobuf

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to link protobuf but I'm getting an undefined reference:
this is my CMAKE file:
I also see in the error code it has a problem with the std::string of the ABI of CPP11 but I don't know if this is the main problem or not because I'm building from a source using GCC 7.3.1

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(cpp_server_side_objects)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

SET(BOOST_LIB boost_system boost_thread)

INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf  REQUIRED)
if(Protobuf_VERBOSE)
    message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
    else()
    message(STATUS "cant find protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
endif()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER SREXOrderRequest.proto)
ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})


add_executable(cpp_server_side_objects main.cpp request.cpp request.h)
target_link_libraries(cpp_server_side_objects proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY} ${BOOST_LIB} )
```

but I'm getting this error messages:

```
====================[ Build | cpp_server_side_objects | Debug ]=================
/home/yaodav/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug --target cpp_server_side_objects -- -j 4
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable cpp_server_side_objects
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::set__symbol(char const*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:618: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::set__myid(char const*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:691: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::set__exdest(char const*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:764: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::set__userinfo(char const*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:837: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::set__dest(char const*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:910: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::SREXOrderRequest(server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:155: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:160: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:165: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:170: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:175: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:325: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InlineGreedyStringParser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:336: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InlineGreedyStringParser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:347: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InlineGreedyStringParser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:358: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InlineGreedyStringParser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc:369: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InlineGreedyStringParser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Swap(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::Arena*)':
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:326: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:327: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:326: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:327: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:326: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o:/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:327: more undefined references to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)' follow
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::WriteStringMaybeAliased(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)':
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:719: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream::WriteStringMaybeAliasedOutline(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_set__symbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:607: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_mutable__symbol[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:630: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_set__myid(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:680: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_mutable__myid[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:703: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_set__exdest(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:753: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_mutable__exdest[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:776: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_set__userinfo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:826: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_mutable__userinfo[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:849: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_set__dest(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:899: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o: In function `server_side_order::SREXOrderRequest::_internal_mutable__dest[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/cpp_server_side_objects/cmake-build-debug/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.h:922: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN17server_side_order16SREXOrderRequestE[_ZTVN17server_side_order16SREXOrderRequestE]+0x20): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/SREXOrderRequest.proc.pb.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTVN17server_side_order16SREXOrderRequestE[_ZTVN17server_side_order16SREXOrderRequestE]+0x48): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [cpp_server_side_objects] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_server_side_objects.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [cpp_server_side_objects] Error 2
```

how to fix it?
tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010398/how-to-link-google-protobuf-libraries-via-cmake-on-linux) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824194/cmake-with-google-protocol-buffers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573702/cant-use-protobuf-in-cmakelists-txt) and with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043184/cmake-doesnt-work-with-google-protobuf) also with no luck.

Comment: If you have checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043184/cmake-doesnt-work-with-google-protobuf), then why do you use **wrong variable name** - `PROTOBUF_LIBRARY` - instead of the correct one - `Protobuf_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I change the `target_link_libraries` line from `${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}`  to `${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}` and still the same errors

Comment: Try `find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)` followed by `target_link_libraries(... protobuf::libprotobuf)`

Comment: @yaodav Did you figure it out?

Comment: Please provide the 'link.txt' file. It should be in your CMake build folder.

Comment: @phreed i got tired of trying so I used other solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The `protobuf_generate_cpp` command in CMake seems to cause a problem in linking the source and header files created from the *.proto file with the necessary libraries.

My workaround was as follows. After obtaining the files created from the proto file, it was to close it so that it would not be created again.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
## Protocol Buffers
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\DevTools\\vcpkg\\packages\\protobuf_x64-windows" "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\DevTools\\vcpkg\\packages\\protobuf_x64-windows\\include")
include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
#protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS src/protocolbuffers/person.proto) # this line
# copy the generated files to the build directory
file(COPY ${PROTO_HDRS} DESTINATION src/protocolbuffers)
file(COPY ${PROTO_SRCS} DESTINATION src/protocolbuffers)
message(STATUS "debug protobuf lib location:${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "debug protobuf include location:${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "proto source files:${PROTO_SRCS}")
message(STATUS "proto header files:${PROTO_HDRS}")
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

...

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        ${HEADER_FILES}
        ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS}
        )
```

...

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ...
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        )
```